# How to store data about a specific node in a Binary search Tree

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am fairly new to Binary trees, as of now i only know how to store single data such as an integer.  I want to know how I can store data about a specific node in a binary search tree.

For example I want to use a binary search tree to store data about a person whereby each node corresponds to a specific person and I want to store data about their age, place of birth and their grade.

So lets say I have text file that I want to load into the BST with data. The textfile has headings `[PersonName, age, place of birth, grade]` and under each heading it will have the data for example `[jack, 18, england, B]`. will this be possible and how can it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can store as much information in each node of your tree as you want.

The problem, I suspect you have, is that you can only efficiently search for *one* piece of information, as the structure of the tree depends on the sort order of that field.

If you want to be able to search for multiple different fields in O(log(n)) time, you'll have to keep several different trees up-to-date, one tree per field you want to search on.

Comment: So lets say i have text file that i want to load into the BST with data. The textfile has headings [PersonName, age, place of birth, grade] and under each heading it will have the data for example [jack, 18, england, B]. will this be possible and how can it be implemented?

Comment: If you can add some of the code to your original question that you currently use, we can show you how to add the extra fields. Some information about which fields you need to search on would help, too